# Informix prevent duplicate result

Tags: sql, database, informix

I want to find some data, some few result are duplicates,
but I want to filter out the duplicate data.

Example data retrieved:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee   <---Duplicate
aaa, qqq, eee, fff, hhh
bbb, rrr, ggg, lll, mmm
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee   <---Duplicate
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee   <---Duplicate
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, lll
```

Example data that I want:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee   <---Just one copy
aaa, qqq, eee, fff, hhh
bbb, rrr, ggg, lll, mmm
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, lll
```

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table
```